# Is it practical to breed new cultivars at home?

Tags: pollination, cultivar

Is it sensible and possible for a home gardener to attempt to create new cultivars (e.g. of citrus) via manual/controlled pollination in a home garden without specialist equipment?

For instance, if I wanted to cross two different apple cultivars is it easily achievable without using specialist equipment to prevent the flowers from being accidentally fertilised by the wrong pollen?

Comment: Not a proper answer to the breeding, but "Seed to Seed" by Suzanne Ashworth describes relatively simple techniques to prevent crossing in vegetables (e.g. bagging ears of corn or tying off squash blossoms). I presume that similar techniques would work for fruit trees.

Comment: The answer is yes, but it is going to vary widely. For an extreme case, Hexlectris orchids can't even be propagated - so no in that case. Some features will make it easier - for example, plants which quickly reach maturity will be much easier. E.g. it will be much easier to breed peppers (maturity in perhaps 6 months) versus trees (years). Quicker breeding cycles speed up the process, making it practical in home locations and timescales. Similarly, plant size is a factor (you can grow a lot of peppers in the space taken by a couple of trees).

Comment: Is your question meant to encompass plants generally, or just fruit trees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is doable. The more crosses you do, the more likely you will come up with something good. The more cultivars that exist for whatever you are breeding the less likely you will come up with an improvement.

Smaller plants would be amenable to home breeding. Large trees like apples would be difficult to come up with an improvement over other varieties.

Comment: Regarding "Large trees like apples would be difficult to come up with an improvement over other varieties" presumably because it takes so long to propagate and grow to be big enough to produce fruit?

Comment: No because for a home gardener having many large trees isn't practical. If you have 1+ acres to devote to plant breeding this problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

When I was young my father had many apple trees, from different cultivars. He kept some seeds from his own apples and grew them into plants. He reserved a stroke of his land, where he planted the young trees, it must have been like 20-30 small trees (packed close to each other like bushes). It took some years before they would finally produce apples, and then he judged which apples were good in taste, pest resistant, and were different to already known cultivars. Finally the one that was best was used for transplantation and grafting and he removed the less successful trees.

It can take years before you have a new cultivar, but you only need space and time for it (pollination is done by insects or wind).